# Jquery Ketchup Form Validation not initializing required fields

Tags: jquery, validation

We are trying to implement jquery ketchup

demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/

and use required fields for the name, email and phone fields we have included all the markup and I think I have it setup properly but the form fields are not validating...

You can see my sample here... thx for any assistance I have been staring at this for hours...

http://c5.dealercontrol.net/service/service-appointment/

Comment: 50 Bucks via paypal to who ever helps resolve this...

Comment: Is your link still valid? Looks like there's no form on that page.